# Getting cron to run on php:7-fpm image

Tags: php, docker

I've set up a dockerfile using the php:7-fpm image. As well as this image being used to run my site, I want to add a cron to be able to perform regular tasks.

I've created a cron, put it in the correct folder, and running `docker exec -ti myimage_php_1 /bin/bash` then `cron` or if I `tail` the log file all works fine. But I can't get this to work when the container is created, I don't want to have to manually start the cron obviously.

From what I understand, I need to use `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` to run the `cron` command on startup, but every time I do this it stops my site working due to me overriding the necessary `CMD/ENTRYPOINT` functionality of the original php:7-fpm image.

Is there a way to trigger both the cron command and continue as before with the php:7-fpm `CMD/ENTRYPOINT`s?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Create your custom entrypoint.sh, something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cron -f &
docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm
```

Note the `&`, it means "send to background".

Then:

```
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

---

**Approach #2**

But, there is a more sophisticated way that is installing `supervisor`, see [docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) (a demons manager used in docker):

In Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install supervisor
COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
...
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

supervisord.conf

```
[program:cron]
command = cron -f

[program:php]
command = docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm
```

Some troubleshooting commands:

```
docker exec <container-id> supervisorctl status
docker exec <container-id> supervisorctl tail -f php
docker exec <container-id> supervisorctl tail -f cron
docker exec <container-id> supervisorctl restart php
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done the trick on my original question. I have a second problem though, in that when I run it through the entrypoint.sh file, I can't change the user with `USER nginx` anymore and `su - nginx` doesn't seem to do anything. I need the cron to be running but, the user to be `nginx`. If I do `USER nginx` in the Dockerfile, I don't have permission to start the cron in entrypoint.sh. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Put your crontab info in /etc/crontab and edit it adding the username before the command: https://serverfault.com/a/352837/171205

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, the problem is that cron isn't running, so I need to start it...but at the point it runs entrypoint.sh, my user isn't root (because I need it to be `USER nginx` for my app), so I get `cron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied`. It's driving me insane!

Comment: Cron must to run as root anyway. What you have to do is tell cron that run that command as another user, which is a cron syntax. Does it make sense?

Comment: hmm ok. Then maybe the problem is elsewhere in my application. Is it correct that my docker containers should always run as root? When I run anything but 'nginx' as the user, I get problems building my cache due to permissions creating folders in my main application (symfony 3 application).

Comment: Install sudo and do `sudo -u username your_command...` that you can use inside cron too

Comment: but that would only be for cron commands, my whole app relies on 'nginx' being the user. It seems strange to me that my image needs to run as root. I need a way to build the image as root, start the cron when my container starts, then switch to the 'nginx' user after. Is that possible? `su - nginx` in my entrypoint.sh doesn't work.

Comment: Turned out the last part of this puzzle was a permissions issue on Symfony cache/logs. `RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data` in my dockerfile resolved the issue and everything's running as expected again! Thank you for your help/patience on this @robert

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. You're welcome!

Comment: All this stuff to do a simple cronjob ? Feels like a big big step backwards somehow

Comment: @Robert can you please say what `docker-php-entrypoint` means ? It's unclear what this is and why is it there.

Comment: It's the script that vanillia image will use to start up: https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.4.0RC1-fpm/images/sha256-45116514d977df6bda2b5545e2ce75b58221f157ddc3f24bbaf2c2536158ef04

Comment: I'm not sure if this ever worked for anyone (I have to assume it did) but with recent `php:7.2-apache` image I had to use `CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]` .  Else it cannot find the config, and, it will try to fork.

Comment: As @mritalian says, I also had to add -n -c "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf" to get the container to stay up. Supervisor really doesn't seem to like to run as root.

I'm curious if there's any particular advantages/disadvantages to each solution (entrypoint vs supervisor), aside from the extra dependency (on supervisor).