# Docker - docker-compose: php-fpm works from image, but don't work from build in Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following docker-compose.

```
version: "2"
services:
  nginx:
      image: nginx:latest
      restart: always
      ports:
          - "8026:80"
      volumes:
          - ./web:/var/www/html
          - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      links:
          - fpm
  fpm:
      image: php:7.2-fpm
      #build: php-fpm/.
      restart: always
      volumes:
          - ./web:/var/www/html
          - ./php-fpm/msmtprc:/etc/msmtprc
      expose:
          - "9000"
```

It works fine and I see my page when I open the related URL.

But after commenting

```
  image: php:7.2-fpm
```

and uncommenting

```
  build: php-fpm/.
```

and using such Dockerfile in php-fpm/, I got 502 error in nginx and such error in the logs:

> nginx_1  | 2018/08/02 21:19:43 [error] 6#6: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.176.1, server: , request: "GET /report/post.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.176.2:9000", host: "api.mytestdomain.com"
>
> FROM php:7.2-fpm
>
> RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install msmtp mutt
>      RUN echo 'sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/msmtp -t"' > >/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mail.ini
>
> RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
>
> # Add crontab file in the cron directory
>      ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron
>
> # Give execution rights on the cron job
>      RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron
>
> # Apply cron job
>      RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron
>
> # Create the log file to be able to run tail
>      RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
>
> # Run the command on container startup
>      CMD ["cron", "-f"]

Why does php-fpm stop working?

P.S.
I also see the following difference:

When I use `image`, I get

> fpm_1    | [02-Aug-2018 21:47:50] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
>   fpm_1    | [02-Aug-2018 21:47:50] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

during docker-compose up.

If I'm using Dockerfile, seems that fpm don't start even

P.P.S.

Looks like problem is in the `CMD ["cron", "-f"]` line. Do somebody have a workaround to have `cron` and `fpm` running in the same container?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting cron to run on php:7-fpm image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198700/getting-cron-to-run-on-php7-fpm-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the logs of the container, it's happening because as you say fpm don't start, it can be any error after build initial  php:7.2-fpm container, for example, failed to install cron

Comment: I have adjusted my answer. I removed everything except "FROM php:7.2-fpm" from dockerfile and still have the same problem. Where can I find aditional logs, except logs that I see during docker-compose up? I see Creating api-bitbucket_fpm_1  ... done there, but I don't see fpm_1 ready to handle connections

Comment: @freento well, strange, 
type "docker logs  api-bitbucket_fpm_1" to check the logs

Comment: also after changing build file you need to rebuild container 'docker-compose build' command

Comment: returns nothing
root@my ~ # docker logs api-bitbucket_fpm_1
root@my ~ #

Comment: wait, probably I really forgot to rebuild. Let's check

Comment: yes, looks like issue is really because CMD ["cron", "-f"]. Do you know any workaround?

Comment: I need more details, but try to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198700/getting-cron-to-run-on-php7-fpm-image